# How can i make this code, more Ruby-esque?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

```
unless scope.nil?
  @page ||= Page.find(id, :scope => Page.find(scope) )
else
  @page ||= Page.find(id)
end
```

Comment: In the future, please indent code by four spaces so that it actually looks like `code` when shown on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@page ||=  Page.find id, :scope => (Page.find scope if scope)
```

Comment: this is the neatest certainly, and as mentioned in the end its down to preference of course.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit DRYer:

```
find_opts = scope.nil? ? {} : {:scope => Page.find(scope)}
@page ||= Page.find(id, find_opts)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write the block in question like the following.  It really comes down to preference, but I find this way to be the most readable.

```
@page ||=
  if scope
    Page.find id, :scope => Page.find(scope)
  else
    Page.find id
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
@page ||= unless scope.nil?
  Page.find(id, :scope => Page.find(scope))
else
  Page.find(id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
@page ||= scope.nil? ? Page.find(id) : Page.find(id, :scope => Page.find(scope))
```